# shell script pattern matching

Tags: bash, shell

Need help on shell script.

I have following result in a file

```
name-label ( RW)    : host1
      networks (MRO): 1/ip: 192.168.1.2; 0/ip: 192.168.1.10

name-label ( RW)    : host2
      networks (MRO): 1/ip: 192.168.1.15; 1/ipv6/0: fe80::9060:b6ff:fec1:7bbb; 0/ip: 192.168.1.20; 0/ipv6/0: fe80::286d:7cff:fefe:3ed7
```

I want only the hostname and corresponding 0/ip value from file. Final output will be

```
host1 192.168.1.10
host2 192.168.1.20
```

Comment: I would use Perl, but awk would be a good tool for this, too.  You could do it with sed, but it's not really natural for dealing with patterns that are split between lines.  Don't have time to work out an answer, but someone else will, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl solution:

```
perl -ne '/^name-label .*: (.+)/ and $name = $1; m(0/ip: ([0-9.]+)) and print "$name $1\n"'
```

Name-label is stored in a variable, it's printed with the IP when processing the next line.

Comment: Where should be the file name?

Comment: @user2584292: At the very end.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash
 grep  ") :" FILENAME |   sed 's/.*) ://' | sed 's/networks.*ip://' | sed 's/;.*//'
```

FILENAME is your file.